# Lag when not attached to debugger

Tags: android

I am developing a opengl solitare game for android. the game is simple so it is implemented using GLSurface and GLRenderer and no native code.

I flip a card when it is selected by rotating a textured opengl quad. The flip slows to about quarter speed every 10 - 20 flips. it will do this for 1 or 2 flips and then it goes back to normal. The lag does not occur when attached to the debugger, it only occurs when not connected to the debugger (usb cable removed from device). When attached to the app with the debugger it never happens.

I thought it might be garbage collection so I have profiled and eliminated waste in time and space usage. It doesn't seem to help.

Just can't understand why it would happen when not connected to the debugger. If anything it seems like the opposite should be true. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the debugger was not the problem. Being connected to power was the problem. My device, Galaxy Note 2 behaves differently when connected to power. Connecting the USB cable also connected power and so the problem would not occur.

The Solution was to switch my debugging connection from USB to TCPIP (over wifi). Now the problem is occurring with or without the debugger.